# how to use docvalues in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, datastax

I am trying to put docvalues on some of the fields which we use a lot for sorting. In order to avoid the fieldCache and rather use the doc values on disk i am using something like following in the schema.xml

```
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="date" docValues="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" omitPositions="true" termVectors="false" termPositions="false" termOffsets="false" type="TrieDateField"/>
```

I wanted to know that is that enough for using the forward index rather then fieldCache while sorting on this field, or do i have to send something like

```
q:date:[NOW/HOUR-1HOUR TO NOW/HOUR]&fieldCache:false
```

in each query also while doing sorting on this field.

I am using Datastax 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently that should be enough. As per official Solr documentation on [docValues](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/DocValues):

> To use docValues, you only need to enable it for a field that you will
>   use it with.

Also please pay attention to:

> If you have already indexed data into your Solr index, you will need
>   to completely re-index your content after changing your field
>   definitions in schema.xml in order to successfully use docValues.

Btw, I would also like to ensure your schema.xml is 100% clear: `... type="TrieDateField"`. I'm under assumption that it should be rather `... type="date"` (`date` is predefined fieldType with implementation of `solr.TrieDateField`).